# Format string using php to insert into mysql db

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I have the following string:

```
$result = "category,date,product,cost
car,10/10/2005,toyota,3000
bike,12/12/2007,yamaha,1000";
```

I need to arrange the string into the best format to insert into a database (needs to be efficient as there might be lots of data also first row will not be needed).

The string is on new lines, so I can:

```
$n = explode("\n", $result);
```

which puts it in this format:

```
[0] => category,date,product,cost
[1] => car,10/10/2005,toyota,3000
[2] => bike,12/12/2007,yamaha,1000
```

now how would i go about formatting this to insert in a db, once again the solution needs to be efficient (for performance), also I would like the first row to not be inserted and finally on the insert I wish for the date to not be inserted.

Hope it makes sense, thanks for the help in advance.

--------edit---------------

The table (item) is structured with the following fields:

```
category, product, cost
```

thanks

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: we don't know your db structure, so don't know how to format anything

Comment: apologies, table structure added.

Comment: i think you missed **date**

Comment: Hi, i didn't I intentionally missed it. I do not want to store date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to have a similar string with the same columns every time, then you could do something like this:

```
$n = explode("\n", $result);

// skip the first row since it's just column names
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($n); $i++)
{
  $cat = $n[$i][[0]; // category
  $date = $n[$i][[1]; // date
  $prod = $n[$i][[2]; // product
  $cost = $n[$i][[3]; // cost

  // and you can put it into a query like so
  $sql = "insert into myTable ('category', 'date', 'product', 'cost') values ('$cat', '$date', '$prod', '$cost')";
}
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: str_getcsv() as previously mentioned would be a better idea

Comment: Possibly so, I was just trying to offer a simple solution.

Comment: str_getcsv is simpler than your approach

Comment: Sorry, Marc, I was just showing the code for demonstrational purposes.

Comment: I would encourage each of you, Dagon and Marc, to show your solutions so Dino can get a better example, since you know more than me :)

Comment: @user1477388 thanks for your help, much appreciated. I agree there a sql injection holes here but not worried about that as I will adjust code accordingly and the solution is great. As I am looking for efficiency I will also investigate str_getcsv and see how that will perform against your solution. But at least for now I am up and running so thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Improving from previously answered post:

```
$n = explode("\n", $result);

// skip the first row since it's just column names

$sql = "insert into myTable ('category', 'date', 'product', 'cost') values ";

for ($i = 1; $i <= count($n); $i++)
{
  $cat = $n[$i][[0]; // category
  $date = $n[$i][[1]; // date
  $prod = $n[$i][[2]; // product
  $cost = $n[$i][[3]; // cost

  $sql .= "('$cat', '$date', '$prod', '$cost'),";
}

$sql = trim($sql, ",");

if(count($n) != 0)
    mysql_query($sql)
```

This gives you just one single query which will insert multiple rows.